# Where does the Kurrent letter-form for E come from?

Tags: middle-ages, imperial-germany, writing

The old German cursives, both Suetterlin and Kurrent, have several peculiar features compared to modern German cursive handwriting. One is a double-stroke letter-shape for [E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent#/media/File:Deutsche_Kurrentschrift.svg). Most introductory treatments, including the Wiki page, describe Kurrent as originating from some mediaeval cursive writing style.

I know that some specimens of Old Roman cursive also show this peculiar double-stroke E (especially on wax tablets; see eg page 14 of [this](http://guindo.pntic.mec.es/jmag0042/LATIN_PALEOGRAPHY.pdf) manual). Is this a coincidence, or is there any continuity between Old Roman cursive and Kurrent that would explain the odd two-stroke E?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54830/german-kurrent-e-and-greek-letter-eta